# Natural Transformations From Reader Bool To Maybe

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I'm reading Bartosz's awesome blog, and following along on challenge question 3, I'm a bit stumped:

https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations/

*Q3: define some natural transformations from `Reader Bool` to `Maybe`*

I have defined the Reader functor as:

```
newtype Reader e a = Reader (e->a)

runReader :: Reader e a -> e -> a
runReader (Reader f) env = f env

instance Functor (Reader e) where
    fmap f (Reader g) = Reader (\x -> f (g x))
```

and I want to find a natural transformation

```
n :: Reader Bool a -> Maybe a
```

My intuition is that if `Reader`'s environment is `True`, I can have a `Just a`, and if `False`, then the natural transformation projects to `Nothing`. But that feels slightly monadic, or like a `Maybe` nested inside a `Reader`, like `Reader Bool (Maybe Int)`, so I'm not sure.

I can't concieve of how to do that. The best I have is:

```
n :: Reader Bool a -> Maybe a
n (Reader f) = Just (f True)
```

But this cannot take into account the environment, nor return `Nothing`.

I want to build a structure that commutes, building a square out of `fmap`, and natural transformations.

For ex:

```
                          nat
Reader Bool Int +---------------------------> Maybe Int
     +                                            +
     |                                            |
     |                                            |
     |                                            |
     |    fmap show                               |  fmap show
     |                                            |
     |                                            |
     |                                            |
     |                                            |
     v                  nat                       v
Reader Bool String  +--------------------------> Maybe String
```

can you help me fill in the gaps?

Comment: You want `n` to use the environment, but, since you have only the Reader, there is no environment and you have to provide it yourself. I feel that `Just (f True)`, `Just (f False)` and `Nothing` are all natural transformations between these functors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I've already said in a comment, you want n to use the environment, but, since you have only the Reader, there is no environment and you have to provide it yourself.

Evidently, these are in fact three *distinct* natural transformations `Reader Bool a -> Maybe a`:

```
n (Reader f) = Just (f True)

n (Reader f) = Just (f False)

n (Reader f) = Nothing
```

Let's prove there are no more. In category-theoretic terms, the functor `Reader Bool a` is just `Hom(Bool,_)`. Now, [Yoneda lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_lemma) tells us that

```
Nat(Hom(X,_), F) = F(X)
```

That is, natural transformations from the functor `Hom(X,_)` to a functor `F` are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of the set `F(X)`.

In our case, `X = Bool` and `F = Maybe`, so we obtain

```
Nat(Hom(Bool,_),Maybe) = Maybe Bool
```

`Maybe Bool` contains exactly three elements: `Just True`, `Just False` and `Nothing`, which correspond to the implementations in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: That makes sense! So, there are only 3 possible nat. transformations between `Reader Bool` and `Maybe`, right? Then on question #2 he asks for natural transformations from `Reader ()` to `List`. I came up with: `n (Reader f) = [f ()]` and infinite of `n (Reader f) = [() ... ()]`. Is this accurate?

Comment: @Josh.F, `Reader ()` is morally isomorphic to `Identity`. So you get one element and need to make a list. There is thus one such natural transformation for each natural number (don't forget 0), plus the infinite one. I think.

Comment: @dfeuer Exactly! And Yoneda gives the same: natural transformations `Reader () -> List` correspond to `List ()`.